# Is this code correct?

Tags: numerical-integration, mathematical-optimization

I want to minimize a NIntegrate.

```
f1[A_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[A x , {x, 0, 2}]
f2[A_?NumericQ, B_?NumericQ] := f1[A] + B
FindMinimum[f2[A, B], {A, B}]
```

This code is only an example. Is it correct?

Comment: Why don't you try it? Are you looking for a local or a global minimum? On what domain? Your function is not bounded (neither in $A$ or $B$) and you're missing a closing bracket in the first line.

Comment: My doubt is about structure of the code. Is f2 define correctly, for instance?

Comment: It is fine (regardless of what it might do).

Comment: To check if `f2` is defined as expected, you could try to check if it is spits out the expected result. For example `f2[0.,1.]` should return `1.`, `f2[1.,0.]` should return `2`, etc.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too localized; i.e, it applies only to the local situation and needs of its poster and answers will not benefit others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, this code will attempt to minimize the `NIntegrate`. However, it probably won't succeed in the specific case that is written.

On my machine, `FindMinimum` spits out:

> {-2.91499*10^45, {A -> -1.166*10^45, B -> -5.82998*10^44}}

Which strongly implies that there's something fishy going on, since those numbers are both extremely large (and negative) and seemingly unrelated to the problem. Thus, it should probably be concluded that the actual minimum is achieved somewhere beyond that point.

Some quick analysis of the problem should make it clear that the presented question doesn't have a singular minimum:

For all real $B$, if $B'$ is chosen to be strictly less than $B$, then $f2(A,B')<f2(A,B)$. Thus, the minimum is the smallest possible $B$, but there is no real number smaller than all other real numbers. A very similar argument can be made with $A$. Thus, the actual minimum is essentially "Both $A$ and $B$ tend toward negative infinity".

Comment: My doubt is about structure of the code. Is f2 define correctly?

Comment: @user3321 Yes. It might not be the singularly most optimal way to do it, but the numerical methods functions should have no difficulty using it. There are concerns when it's unbounded like this, if it weren't `?NumericQ` `FindMinimum` could probably tell you that it was unbounded instead of giving a spurious negative value like this.